# Why is my div lower than the others when contented?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying out with div overflows. And I am encountering the problem that the div is not displaying 'normally'. This is a simple HTML and CSS and I hope someone can explain me the problem?

I was expecting that the boxes to be displaying in the same line.

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='box'>
    hihi
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

http://codepen.io/ycmjason/pen/xbXpmV/

Comment: `display: inline-block` has `baseline` for a default value for `vertical-align`. Just change that to `top` and it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `vertical-align: top;` property on **`box class`**.

It should be:

```
.box{
    display:inline-block;
    **vertical-align: top;**
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:15px;
    background: #55CC55;
}
```

Comment: can you please describe why I need it?

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: You need it because when you use display: inline-block; vertical-align has baseline as default value.

Answer (score 1):

The default vertical align value for a div is `baseline`, this means, the box moves to the bottom as soon as you write text in it. If there's no text, there is no baseline to be aligned to, so they just hop on the top. To fix it add `vertical-align: top;` to your .box.